# Appending output to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i append the output of `ip` to a string

```
import ipaddress
import random


 def main():
     for _ in range(10000):
         ip = (ipaddress.IPv4Address(random.randint(0,2 ** 32)))
         print(ip)

 main()
```

Comment: How do you think that you should `append the output of ip to a string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `join` method of `str` on a list of strings.

```
import ipaddress
import random

acc = []

def main():
    for _ in range(10000):
        ip = (ipaddress.IPv4Address(random.randint(0,2 ** 32)))
        print(ip)
        # append to a list instead of printing
        acc.append(str(ip)) # cast the ip to a string

main()
print(" ".join(acc)) # using space as separator
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `str.join` using a comprehension:

```
', '.join(ipaddress.IPv4Address(random.randint(0,2 ** 32)) for _ in range(10000))
```